# What is the term for saying something negative fishing for positive comments?

Tags: expressions, terminology

Help me!  There is a term for when people say or post something negative or complaining but in reality they are fishing for positive (compliments).  What is this term?!

Comment: As you mention, they are fishing for compliments.

Comment: Do you want a *verb* describing what they are doing?  A *noun* saying what sort of person they are? or an *adjective* describing their attributes?  Could you give an example sentence with a blank where you want the word to go. Then we can see which you need.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's any better term than "fishing for compliments".

Comment: It is like when people post negative comments in an effort to bring about attention to the opposite, somewhat like fishing for a complement

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for a verb.

Comment: @Candice - Well there is one here but it's rather coarse (adults only). https://www.powerthesaurus.org/fishing_for_compliments/synonyms

Comment: @chaslyfromUK None of those examples are single verbs, and the one marked as vulgar is a three-word noun.

Comment: @Jason Bassford - "being an attention whore" is a verb phrase deriving from "to be an attention whore".  You can conjugate it, e.g. "He is being an attention whore"  You can also use the first one in a verbal form, "to emotionally m*st*rb*te"

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Perhaps technically, but it's stretching it in this case. It might actually *be* a verb phrase, but it has more the quality of a noun phrase. A more extreme version in answer to a verb would be *being an attention whore when everybody else tells me I shouldn't*. A verb phrase? Technically, because of the *being* in front of it—but there are 10 words after that form a noun phrase. Adding *being* to the front is a kind of cheat.

Comment: You guys rock, but it still isn't what i'm looking for! lol  Keep at it!  I'm thinking it was a literary term...litotes (only that isn't it).

Comment: @ Jason Bassford - I don't think it's cheating. After all the original phrase "fishing for compliments" wasn't a single word. You can paraphrase "She's fishing for compliments" with "She's being an attention whore." However, if you insist, "Look, she's attention-whoring again!"

Comment: @Candace Looking up *litotes* led me to think of **equivocate**, which I think is *close* to the type of verb you're looking for, but probably not quite—because it lacks the aspect of self-aggrandizement you're looking for.. (And **aggrandize** is a verb, but it lacks the sense of doing it in a backward way …)

Comment: Like this? Person A: I'm ugly. Person B: No, you're beautiful.